# Why is a PPA software labeled "Proprietary" in Software Center?

Tags: software-center

For example, for [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~costales/+archive/ubuntu/anoise), the Software Center in Ubuntu 18.04 shows it as Proprietary:

[image]

How could I, as the developer, change this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related (but not a dupe): [Open Source software mislabeled in Ubuntu Software Center (USC) as Proprietary](https://askubuntu.com/q/1052688/504066)

Comment: I made that post PerlDuck and I contacted Costales because of it. It doesn't seem to be an issue with USC but more so with the apps themselves so Costales is trying to fix that through his own app, and he wants to know how to do it.

Comment: @TioTROM Yes, I understood that. And I didn't want to say _your_ Q is a dupe of _costales'_ Q (or the other way round). I just wanted to say: Hey, other readers, please look: there's another Q addressing a similar issue which (at least to me) is worth reading.